# Application targeting multiple devices (Win 7 Phone, iOS, Android, Win 8)

Tags: asp.net, ipad, windows-phone-7, microsoft-metro

I am working on a small hobby app - which would show some charts, and would be accessible by people using their mobile devices. I come from a Microsoft development background  - have used Telerik, Infragistics controls in the past, and loved them.

From my research so far  - it seems like I will have to build an app that outputs HTML5 for maximum compatibility.

I like the ComponentOne controls so far - http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioiPhone/

I am also looking at the KendoUI (http://www.kendoui.com/) - I like it, but seems like it is all javascript, and I have very limited experience there.

Are there any components/frameworks that you guys would recommend ? Paid components are fine.

I just want a few charts that are accessible everywhere. I know I could use  MVC - and design a different a different UI layer for each platform, but I dont have that much time.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to consider ASP.NET MVC and expose it as a web site, since ASP.NET MVC 4 will have explicit mobile support.

Also, if you want an actual application, you could consider various products like:

- http://www.phonegap.com/
- http://www.appcelerator.com/

it depends what type of feature you want to make available.  Must of the HTML-based frameworks require JavaScript.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Sencha? While I have not played with the Sencha charts, I have tried other widgets.

[www.sencha.com](http://www.sencha.com)

You can put together ASP.net MVC at the backend with Sencha consisting of HTML5 + Javascript

Answer (score 1):

Stick with ComponentOne if you want to keep working in WebForms and aren't OK with JavaScript. They have [HTML5 charts](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/BarChartASPNET/) that work everywhere too.

If you are looking to move to MVC/JavaScript then ComponentOne has [Wijmo](http://wijmo.com) too. Wijmo is 30 jQuery UI widgets including the same HTML5 charts they extend in WebForms.